# How can I attempt to restart() JMS connection in concurrent environment?

Tags: java, jboss, jms

I have a JMS application which tries to read from a JBosss Queue. I implemented `MessageListener` on my class and used the `onMessage()` to receive messages

```
public class JBossConnector implements MessageListener, AutoCloseable {}
```

Here is my method:

```
/**
 * The listener method of JMS. It listens to messages from queue: 'jbossToAppia'
 * If the message is of type MessageObject, then transfer that to Appia
 *
 * @param message JMS Message
 */
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {

    // receive the message from jboss queue: 'jbossToAppia'
    // then post it to appia
    if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
        try {

            MessageObject messageObject = (MessageObject) ((ObjectMessage) message).getObject();
            System.out.printf("JbossConnector: MessageObject received from JBOSS, %s\n", messageObject.getMessageType());

            component.onMessageFromJboss(properties.getProperty("target.sessionID"), messageObject);

        } catch (MessageFormatException exception) {
            logger.error(ExceptionHandler.getFormattedException(exception));
            ExceptionHandler.printException(exception);
        } catch (JMSException exception) {
            ExceptionHandler.printException(exception);
            restart();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%s: MessageFormatException(Message is not of the format MessageObject)\n", this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

Whenever I find a `JMSException` I try to restart JBoss connection (Context, Connection, Session, Receiver, Sender). What my doubt is that I've read `onMessage()` uses multiple threads to receive messages from queue (correct me if I'm wrong).

When the JBoss queue connection severs, there would be at least some queues that throw this exception. That means they all will try to `restart()` the connection which is a waste of time (`restart()` first closes all the connections, sets the variables to null and then attempt to initiate connections).

Now I could do something like

```
synchronized (this){
    restart();
}
```

or use `volatile` variables. But that would not guarantee that other threads won't attempt to `restart()` when current threads finishes the `restart()` operation (again correct me if I'm wrong).

Is there any solution to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onMessage()` of a `MessageListener` is indeed run from its own thread so you'll need proper concurrency controls. I think the simplest solution would just be to use a [`java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html). For example, in your `restart()` method you could do something like this:

```java
private void restart() {
   AtomicBoolean restarting = new AtomicBoolean(false);

   if (!restarting.getAndSet(true)) {
      // restart connection, session, etc.
   }
}
```

This will make the `restart()` method effectively idempotent. Multiple threads will be able to call `restart()` but only the first thread which calls it will actually cause the resources to get re-created. All other calls will return immediately.

Comment: thank you so much. I was about to synchronize everything and make a whole lot of mess